# How can i get all value from child node using htmlagilitypack?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

How can i get value from child node like href value and add them to list using html agility pack with the class name of parent node?

I have tried this code but fail

```
var pagedivs = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("div").Where(e => e.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("pagination"))
                .Where(k => k.Descendants().Any(t => t.Name == "li")).ToList();
```

HTML code in web:

```
<div class="pagination">
        <ul class="pagination-list">
            <li class="hidden-phone current"><a title="1" href="" class="pagenav">1</a></li>
            <li class="hidden-phone"><a title="2" href="/collections/remarkable-products?page=2" class="pagenav">2</a></li>
            <li><a title="Next page" href="/collections/remarkable-products?page=2" class="pagenav"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
        <input type="hidden" name="limitstart" value="0">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `href` value specifically, you can do something like this:

```
var links = document.DocumentNode
    .Descendants("div") // 1
    .Where(div => div.HasClass("pagination")) // 2
    .First() // 3
    .Descendants("a") // 4
    .Select(a => a.GetAttributeValue("href", "")) // 5
    .Where(link => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(link)) // 6
    .ToList();
```

1. Get all descendant `div`s. This includes both children **and** children's children
2. Only keep the `div` that has the class `pagination`
3. Select the first `div` that match our criteria
4. Once again get all descendants, but this time the `a`s
5. Get the value of the `a`s `href` value
6. Filter out the links with empty values (like the first one in the submitted HTML